# Compute definite integral by hand

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How can I compute

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^3t}{(x^2+t^2)^2} \, \mathrm{dt}$$

by hand?

Comment: Hint: $u=x^2+t^2$.

Comment: Pretty close to elementary, isn't it?  Seeing the "$x^2+ t^2$" in the denominator and "$tdt$" in the numerator, my first thought would be "try $u= x^2+ t^2$.  You realize, do you not, that "x" is a constant here? What is "du"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\int \frac{x^3t}{(x^2+t^2)^2}dt$$
$$=x^3\int \frac{t}{(x^2+t^2)^2}dt$$
$$u=(x^2+t^2)\Rightarrow du=2tdt$$
$$=x^3\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^2}du$$
$$=x^3\frac{1}{2}\int u^{-2}du$$
It's pretty simple from here, you can simply use the power rule, substitute $u$ back in and simplify to have the indefinite integral. From there just compute the bounds.

Comment: Thanks, now that I look at it it was actually pretty easy. The x² confused me.